# Editing a question title to replace specific terms with a synonyms when the original was perfectly clear?

Tags: discussion, edits

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259472/why-does-c-not-allow-concatenating-strings-when-using-the-conditional-operator) a user replaced the word ternary in the title with the word conditional, with an admonition in the edit message warning the op that the ternary operator was in fact called the conditional operator and should not be called the ternary operator.

I can see that using one term over the other might be less confusing for some people, but I've (with very few exceptions) always heard the **?** operator referred to as the ternary operator  not the conditional operator. This seems like a trivial edit over a matter of personal preference.

I know edits to improve a question are encouraged, but are edits to re-word a title to use synonymous terms I am more familiar with something I should be doing? Particularly without any apparent increase in clarity in the meaning.

Comment: You're right, I've rolled back the edit.

Comment: a ternary operator is any operator that takes 3 arguments. The conditional operator is a ternary operator but it's not the only one (although in particular programming languages it might be the only one).

Comment: So it's a case of tightening the scope?